# Android SQLite - "if" SQLite table column null then execute

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to write code which checks the table if the column value is null and then execute the insert function. If not, run the code.

```
Cursor sumw = dbObject.rawQuery(
        "SELECT COMAMOUNT FROM COMMISION",
        null);
sumw.moveToFirst();
int e = sumw.getInt(0);
if(e != 0){
    alerts();
}
```

This is how I tried. I know it must be wrong, because it always sends the alert to insert.

- Table name : COMMISION - DB_COMMISION
- Table column : COMAMOUNT - handle.COM_AMOUNT

Comment: try making Log of sumw.getInt(0).it will help you trace out your problem? if you have already tried,what you are getting there?

Comment: yes Hiral i tried that.... if "e" has a value and if its less than 0 then it works fine but i want to get if e is null.... then it wont work

(I tried it by entering a value to "the column COMAMOUNT" n then it worked )

Comment: Then you should convert this int e to string to check if its null or not.if you will get null then you can insert it else you can let it run some code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
Cursor sumw = dbObject.rawQuery(
                "SELECT COMAMOUNT FROM COMMISION",
                null);

if(sumw.moveToNext()){
   String no = sumw.getString(0);
   if( no != null ) {
      alerts();
   }  
}
```